# CodeIgniter not receiving post from autocomplete jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-autocomplete

I must have spent 30 solid hours trying to figure out this out. CodeIgniter doesn't seem to be receiving the data from the autocomplete script and for the life of me I can't figure out why.

View

```
<head>
        <script src="https://localhost/testsite/assets/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>    
        <script src="https://localhost/testsite/assets/js/jquery/jquery-ui.css" type="text/javascript" ></script>   
</head>
<input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" />


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var postcode = $('#postcode').val();
    $("#postcode").autocomplete({
        source: "postcode/get_postcode", // path to the get_birds method
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: { postcode: postcode}

  });
});
</script>
```

Controller

```
    $this->load->model('postcode_model');

    $postcode = $this->input->post('postcode');

    if(isset($postcode)){
        $this->postcode_model->get_postcode($postcode);
    }else{
        $data['error'] = $postcode;
            $this->load->view('error', $data);
    }
  }
```

Model
    class postcode_model extends CI_Model {

```
  function get_postcode($q){

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT postcode
                                   FROM geo 
                                   WHERE postcode LIKE '$q%' 
                                 ");     

    $row_set = array();

     if($query->num_rows > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){

            $row_set[] = $row['postcode']; 

        }

        echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }

    }
}
```

If I send a test integar to the model the script does correctly grab the list of postcodes and then displays them in the html so they only problem I seem to be having is actually getting autocomplete to send the text field entry to the Controller

In firebug I get this error:
SyntaxError: syntax error
.ui-helper-hidden {
I tried to post a picture of it but it won't let me due to reputation

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Most likely you have a syntax error somewhere in your JavaScript code therefore no JavaScript is ever executed by browser.

Comment: There are no syntax errors and all the javascript is running except the data is not being received by the model, URLs are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... finally. 
1. Data{} needs to have a different name than your field ID (#postcode) 
2. autocomplete doesn't like POST so use GET

VIEW

```
<input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" />


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#postcode").autocomplete({
    source: "<?php echo base_url('postcode/get_postcode')?>",
    dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        data: { term: $("#postcode").val()},        
  });

});
</script>
```

Controller

```
  function get_postcode(){

    $this->load->model('postcode_model');

    $postcode = $this->input->get('term');



    if(isset($postcode)){
        $this->postcode_model->get_postcode($postcode);
    }else{
        $data['error'] = $postcode;
            $this->load->view('error', $data);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have couple error in script, First as i can see you are not return response as `json`

```
 if(isset($postcode)){
    $this->postcode_model->get_postcode($postcode); // Here
```

change it to

```
if(isset($postcode)){
    $this->output
      ->set_content_type('application/json')
      ->set_output( 
          json_encode( $this->postcode_model->get_postcode($postcode) 
      ));
```

**In JS**

```
 data: { "postcode": postcode} // should be different you have assigned same as key and value
```

and CSS link is also wrong, you have used `<script>` use `<link>`

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://localhost/ozjobs/assets/js/jquery/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: I didn't post the model I will in a sec, it is being encoded in the model and echoed out in a foreach statement

Comment: echo in `model` is bad idea, its limit you from reusing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your html header tag you are including .css file as JavaScript

please use this instead

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://localhost/ozjobs/assets/js/jquery/jquery-ui.css">
```

that is causing the error you mention